# ¿Como evitar que lleguen id´s duplicados a función jquery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy usando fullCalendar, utilizando la función de eventClick para que se expanda un modal mostrando 4 botones para manipular el evento. Aquí esta una parte del código:

**eventClick**

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
      alert(calEvent.id);
      $('#confirmar').modal();
      $('#guardar').click(function(){
        alert(calEvent.id);
      });
}
```

El problema que tengo es que si tengo por ejemplo dos eventos, el primero con `id=1` llamado `fiesta` y el segundo con `id=2` llamado `cine`, si le doy click al evento `fiesta`al entrar a la función los dos `alert` me imprimirá el `id=1` y si cierro el modal y ahora doy click en el evento `cine`, el primer `alert`me imprimira un `id=2`pero dentro de la función `$('#guardar')`el `alert`me imprimirá primero `id=1` y luego `id=2`entonces esto es un problema ya que si quiero borrar un registro al entrar a esta función, se me borrarían ambos eventos.

Comment: ¿Qué alert? ¿Qué modal? Si no pones el código completo para poder reproducir tu problema (los campos HTML de los que hablas y el código Javascript relacionado) no sabremos cómo ayudarte porque no sabremos qué estás haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que pasa es que estas haciendo un binding, cada vez que llamas la función.

```
  $('#guardar').click(function(){
        alert(calEvent.id);
      });
```

Eso, lo repites, en cada event click entonces es como si lo asignaras de nuevo.  La solución fea es:

```
  $('#guardar').off('click'); // le quita todos los eventos asignados
  $('#guardar').on('click', function(){
        alert(calEvent.id);
      });
```

La solución formal es con name spaces... pero es algo difícil de explicar, prueba con esto, te debería funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me funciono, lo dejare como solucion temporal y buscare sobre lo otro que me comentas.